# Is it possible to sort a Cassandra Column Family by a specific column of a list of a user-defined datatype?

Tags: list, sorting, cassandra, nosql, cqlsh

I'm having a little hard time understanding Cassandra. I simply couldn't write this question without making it look like confusing, but as I detail it below it may become clearer.

Suppose I have this datatype that I've created:

```
CREATE TYPE transaction (
    transaction_id UUID,
    value float,
    transaction_date timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (transaction_id, transaction_date)
);
```

PS: I'm using it as if it was a 'class', but that might be a logical mistake of mine, please correct me if it can't be used as such.

Anyway, also I have this Column Family, in which I've created a list of this 'transaction' datatype:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions_history_by_date (
    wallet_address UUID,
    user_id UUID,
    transactions list <transaction>,
    PRIMARY KEY (wallet_address, transaction_date))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (transaction_date DESC);
```

So what I'd like to know if this Column Family above is correct. I'd like to get all the transactions of a wallet, sorted by the transaction date (but the date is a column of the 'transaction' datatype - and to complicate it even more, in this Column Family there's a list of transactions, and not just a single one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, in Cassandra you can sort only on the value of the clustering column - in this case you need to move `transaction_date` into table itself...

Comment: Thank you Alex! By the way, if I put more than one cluster key within the primary key, the sorting would be done according to the cluster key that I specify in the `WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (transaction_date DESC)`, right? But in this case, what would be the use of the cluster column keys that I did not use for the sorting?

Comment: Sorting happens for all clustering columns, if you have multiple clustering columns, the data is sorted first on first one, then data with same value of first column are sorted on 2nd, etc. See this post: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/we-shall-have-order

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Alex's answer, in your situation I think the best approach would probably be to denormalise your table. Rather than using a UDT, you could create something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions_history_by_date (
wallet_address UUID,
user_id UUID,
transaction_id UUID,
value float,
transaction_date timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY ((wallet_address), transaction_date, transaction_id))
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (transaction_date DESC);
```

Now you can make the following query and the results will be sorted by date:

`SELECT * FROM transactions_history_by_date WHERE wallet_address = ...;`

Note that I added `transaction_id` as a second clustering key. If this was omitted the table would not have been able to hold two transactions that had the same wallet_address and the same transaction_date. This is because unique rows are identified by the primary key.

Comment: Very clarifying, thanks Justin! Indeed, from what I've learnt one of the main points of Cassandra would be the denormalisation. Please, may I ask you a few more questions? 1- If there's more than one clustering key, what is the usage of the clustering keys that I'm not using for the sorting? I mean, you said I wouldn't be able to account for two transactions within the same `wallet_address` and `transaction_date`... I'm not exactly sure why.

Comment: Also, 2- How would I be able to link a list of `transaction_id` to a list `transaction_date` and `value`? I was thinking of using UDT to make this linkage possible, as every and each transaction would have specific timestamps and values but if I denormalise the column family and put a list of these transactions properties, I'm not sure how I'd tell `'transaction_id 1 has timestamp x and value y; transaction_id 2 has timestamp z and value v'` and so on...

Comment: 1 - I updated my answer to clarify that the primary key is used to identify unique rows (just like a SQL database). 2- If you want to query by `transaction_id` you'll need to make a second table with a different primary key, and duplicate the data. Something like: `PRIMARY KEY ((transaction_id))` could work, provided that `transaction_id` is globally unique in your application. Cassandra also has Materialised Views, however they are considered experimental and have some caveats so approach with caution - [read this first](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg54073.html).